# Exercise 16, Section 7.2 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, minimal-polynomials, cyclic-decomposition

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with real entries such that $A^2+I=0$. Prove that $n$ is even, and if $n=2k$, then $A$ is similar over the field of real numbers to a matrix of the block form $\begin{bmatrix}0&-I\\I&0\end{bmatrix}$ where $I$ is the $k\times k$ identity matrix.

**My attempt:** Let $m$ and $f$ be minimal and characteristic polynomial of $A$, respectively. $A^2+I=0$ implies $x^2+1$ annihilates $A$. So $m|(x^2+1)$. Since $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{R}$, we have $m=x^2+1$. By theorem 4 section 7.2, $f=(x^2+1)^k$ for some $k\geq 1$. Then $\deg (f)=k\cdot \deg (x^2+1)=2k=n$. Thus $n$ is even.

Suppose $n=2k$. Then $m=x^2+1$ and $f=(x^2+1)^k$. By theorem 3 section 7.2,  $\exists \alpha_1,…,\alpha_r\in V\setminus \{0\}$ with respective $T$-annihilators $p_1,…,p_r$ such that $V=Z(\alpha_1;T)\oplus \cdots Z(\alpha_r;T)$, and $p_{i+1}|p_i$, and $p_1=m$, and $p_1\cdots p_r=f$. Since $p_i|p_1=x^2+1$, we have $p_i=x^2+1$ for all $i\in J_r$. So $p_1\cdots p_r=(x^2+1)^r=f=(x^2+1)^k$ and $r=k$. Then  $\exists B$ basis of $V$ such that
$$[T]_B=\begin{bmatrix}A_1 & & \\ &\ddots & \\ & & A_k\end{bmatrix}$$
where $A_i= \begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\ 1&0\end{bmatrix}\in M_2(\Bbb{R})$ is companion matrix of $p_i$. **How to progress from here?** I think, we can switch rows and columns of $[T]_B$ in a specific way to reach $\begin{bmatrix}0&-I\\ I&0\end{bmatrix}$. Switching columns of $[T]_B$ is like switching elements of $B$. So we obtain ordered basis $B’$. Therefore similarity is preserved. But row permutation don’t preserve similarity ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1025199/861687) is counter example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can apply a permutation similarity to get from your $[T]_B$ to the desired form. In particular: let $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_{2k}$ denote the columns of the size $2k$ identity matrix. We can take
$$
P = \pmatrix{e_1 & e_3 & \cdots & e_{2k-1} & e_2 & e_4 & \cdots & e_{2k}}
$$
and find that if $M$ denotes the desired block form, $M = P^T[T]_B P$.

This permutation matrix $P$ is the [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) $K^{(k,2)}$. To see that this works, it suffices to note that $[T]_B$ is the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) $I \otimes A$, and the desired form is $M = A \otimes I$, where $A = 
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix} \right].
$ As is noted on the "properties" section of the commutation matrix wiki page, we have
$$
M = A \otimes I = K^{(2,k)} (I \otimes A)K^{(k,2)} = P^T [T]_B P.
$$

---

Here's an outline of an alternative proof that we get the desired form. Consider the product $e_i^T(P^T[T]_BP)e_j = (Pe_i)^T[T]_B(Pe_j)$, which is the $i,j$ entry of the result $M = P^T[T]_B P$. You need to show 3 facts:

- If $i = j + k$, then the result is $1$
- If $j = i + k$ , then the result is $-1$
- In all other cases, the result is $0$.

Note that for the original matrix $[T]_B$, we have
$$
e_p [T]_B e_q = \begin{cases}
1 & i \text{ is even and } j = i-1\\
-1 & i \text{ is odd and } j = i+1\\
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I’m not familiar with commutation matrix and Kronecker product. I have look those things up. By any chance, is there a simpler proof?

Comment: @user264745 See my latest edit